# Using a class in the dependencies array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I have a complex functionality that I implemented using a class.
Now I'm trying to use this class in my visual components, however I can't make React subscribe to changes in my class instances' fields.

I feel that I don't understand this behavior, which is even more confusing than the simple case of something not working :)

Here's [a minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-violet-m8sz3m?file=/src/App.js):

```
class Foo {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const foo = useMemo(() => new Foo(1), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`foo has a new value: ${foo.value}`);
  }, [foo.value]);

  function changeValue(nextValue) {
    foo.value = nextValue;
    console.log(foo);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => changeValue(2)}>
        Change value
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `useState` be more appropriate over `useMemo`?

Comment: @Rajesh Since I don't plan to update `foo` entirely, I don't think it makes such a difference. Anyways I'm subscribing to `foo.value`, rather than `foo`

Comment: My point was, `useMemo` is used to memoize not to preserve data. Second, in observer pattern, subscriber is called on assignment. When you change, value is reassigned. But on mutation it doesn't

Comment: `useMemo` will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed use it like `useMemo(() => new Foo(count), [count])` and do your work in class constructor. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render. from `react hook doc`.